# Approach to return updated object after POST and PUT in rest API

Tags: web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am creating rest API using WEB API. However my question is independent of the technology. 
I am supporting POST and PUT on entities. However, when client sends the object for creation, server creates the resource with some extra fields and return the updated object back to client.

For example: If service supports a POST for Employee {Id, Name, Description}. Here Id is generated is server.

```
{
"id": 18,
"name": "dasdsa aa",
"description": " "
}
```

Here **Id** is sent by server. This is simple example. **In case of complex entity what should be the approach to send the updated entity to the client**. Currently I am making an internal call to get to return the updated entity.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? Which entity back to the client?

Comment: Updated the question. Entity means the object sent to server by client and then server sends the updated object to client

Comment: Right, i get that bit, but what's the problem....? I don't actually see a question here

Comment: The question here is to know if there any other approach to return updated object to client?

Comment: Just return the updated object... i don't see the complexity

Comment: You could also return a HTTP status code 200 OK for a successful PUT